# How to replace item in list based off name in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an application in Android Studio that takes DNA and transcribes it to mRNA. I also want to display the corresponding amino acids, but I am a bit stuck. All I can do so far is make a list from the mRNA sequence and cut them up into groups of 3. As my code shows here:

```
package com.example.dnadecode

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import java.nio.channels.NonReadableChannelException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        val dnainput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dnainput)
        val dnaoutput = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        val amino = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.amino)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val ok = dnainput.text
            var okstr = ok.toString().toUpperCase()
            val result = okstr.replace(oldChar = 'G', newChar = '_').replace(oldChar = 'C', newChar = 'G').replace(oldChar = '_', newChar = 'C').replace(oldChar = 'A', newChar = 'U').replace(oldChar = 'T', newChar = 'A')
            val ogamino = result.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
            val newamino = ogamino.chunked(3)
            amino.text = newamino.toString()
            dnaoutput.text = result.toString()
        }
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            dnainput.text.clear()
            dnaoutput.text = ""
            amino.text = ""
        }
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val openURL = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            openURL.data = Uri.parse("https://saucygames05.github.io/DNADecoder/help.html")
            startActivity(openURL)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace each item in the list with the correct amino acid so, for example, instead of th output being:
`[AUG, GAA, UCC]` I want it to display: `[Met, Glu, Ser]` and the same for all the other possible combinations that specify which amino acid is used. This is my first time using kotlin so I am only going off of my knowledge of python and a little bit of java.
My XML:

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="DNA Code:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:text="Translate!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.785"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.203" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dnainput"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:text="mRNA Sequence:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Clear"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="help"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:text="Amino Acids:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: The way the question is written, the only people who'll be able to help you are those who know about amino acids and what all these acronyms mean and how the correspond with each other. Maybe you could write a simpler, abstract description of exactly what you're trying to do. There's some kind of input, and some kind of transformation to get two different kinds of output, but I have no idea what those transformations are so I can't help.

Comment: How can I put this... I just want to change the item in the list based on what it's value is. This can go for any 3 groups of letters, it doesnt have to be amino acids. Like if the item is [123] then can be changed when translated and replaced by the word [Cat] and so forth. Sorry if I made it more complicated than it had to be.

Comment: So there are many specific groups of three letters, each of which has a single string it can be converted to?

Comment: Some go to the same string needed to be converted to. Here is the charts I use: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/86/e9/74/86e974c70785644c1ea24d81146ace94.jpg
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/MSFx7mo6qMmGSYDLaT-Dh2YVTJDsNBWIHrHHW3XD4e53orZn0hc4r0wNByP4dLHNH1E8IgdlgPS5xzg99ct6ik6eUCXWMevE6LxybSTV2CT-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is, specify a mapping from mRna codon to amino acids, one way would be to define a function

```
// Pass mRna codon and get amino acid, this is not complete list
// please refer some authorotative reference to get all the mappings, 
// once you have the mappings then use the below function to codify them
private fun mapToAmino(mRna: String): String{
    return when(mRna){
        // List all the codons that map to a specific amino acid
        "UUU","UUC" -> "Phe" 
        "UUA","UUG" -> "Leu"
        //These six map to "Ser" so list them as comma separated
        "UCU","UCC","UCA","UCG","AGU","AGC" -> "Ser"
        else -> "Not found"
    }
}
```

Then in your `activity` you can do following to get a `list` of amino acids.

```
val result = okstr.replace(oldChar = 'G', newChar = '_').replace(oldChar = 'C', newChar = 'G').replace(oldChar = '_', newChar = 'C').replace(oldChar = 'A', newChar = 'U').replace(oldChar = 'T', newChar = 'A')
val ogamino = result.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
val newamino = ogamino.chunked(3).map { mapToAmino(it) }
// newAmino is a list of all amino acids, given that you defined the mappings correctly
```

*Get mappings from a valid and authoritative source, for example [this](https://www.shsu.edu/academics/agricultural-sciences-and-engineering-technology/documents/mRNAcodonchart.pdf) one looks good but please do your research.*